# how to get magento2 wsdl XML structure

Tags: api, magento2, xml, magento2-dev-beta, wsdl

In magento1 for any request API, WSDL XML structure can be obtained by giving URL http://192.168.0.183/magento1131/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1 in [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/), [storm](https://storm.codeplex.com/) or any other wsdl xml request processor.

For the same in magento2, to get the WSDL XML structure for any API request if i type the URL http://192.168.0.183/NewMagento2/soap?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1 ,its giving error.

In magento1 we can get WSDL XML structure like below

[image]

but getting below error in magento2

[image]

So please let me know how to get magento2 XML structure for any API request

Comment: I tried your url and don't get any errors, can you provide stacktrace?

Comment: @KAndy https://gist.github.com/kandy/dd6592508c5774d9235d - last comment

Comment: According to this page, http://bit.ly/1WP9wCs, the WSDL structure for Customer is http://magentohost/soap?wsdl&services=customerV1

Comment: @SteveJohnson still i'm getting error in SOAPUI, i'm looking for WSDL **XML** structure

Comment: @SteveJohnson please see my edited post

Answer (score 2):

in magento2, the API endpoints are protected. So to download the wsdl, you need authentication.

I know (or maybe I did not find it) that SoapUI for example does not support authenticating for WSDL's.

So I downloaded the WSDL through some other client which can send the authentication header and then added it to SOAP UI from the local downloaded WSDL file.

You need to create a new Integration in the Magento Backend (system -> integrations) and then use the access token in your auth header:

Header:   Authorization: Bearer [access_token]

(http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html)

Comment: Can you tell me which is that other client?

Comment: I mostly use postman for this.  It's a powerful chrome plugin

Answer (score 0):

To get magento2 wsdl xml structure you can use this doc 
: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/soap/bk-soap.html
You can run any of SOAP WSDL request right in a browser to get a response of xml structure or you can use SOAPUI to do this. It's not recommended to use Storm tool for Magento2 SOAP services.